# convert from boost::shared_ptr<T> to boost::shared_ptr<const T>

Tags: c++, boost

```
class T
{};

class UseT
{
public:
    //...
    boost::shared_ptr<const T> getT() const
    {
        return m_t;
    }
private:
    boost::shared_ptr<T> m_t;
};
```

Question> What are the rules used when we convert from `boost::shared_ptr<T>` to `boost::shared_ptr<const T>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shared_ptr<T>` has a converting constructor that allows it to be constructed from `shared_ptr<U>` if it would be valid to convert from `U*` to `T*`, mirroring how built-in pointers work.

```
template<typename U>
  shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<U>& other);
```

(For `std::shared_ptr` the constructor can only be called if `U*` is convertible to `T*`, but for `boost::shared_ptr` I'm not sure if it checks that, or you just get a compiler error for invalid conversions.)

Since `T*` can be converted to `const T*`, the constructor allows you to create a `shared_ptr<const T>` from a `shared_ptr<T>`.